# Using S3 as target for AWS DMS: Uploaded File name doesn't change

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

We are using DMS to get data from SQL Server and load it in S3 bucket, after which the data is finally loaded into Snowflake DB using Snowpipe for Full Load.

Now, in order for Snowpipe to know there is new data in S3 bucket, the filename needs to be different than the last one.  Have tried all the task setting options available (DROP_AND_CREATE, DO_NOTHING, TRUNCATE) to have the file name different, but still not working.  It loads the file name as LOAD00000001.csv

In documentation it shows that file name will be incremental (eg. LOAD00000001.csv, LOAD00000002.csv .. and so on) but it's not happening. Which is why the Snowpipe is not able to register the changes.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.S3.html

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

For DMS the incremental counter is started over from 1 each time the task is run. It does not have a "Don't override existing objects" feature.

Your best bet may be to handle the load yourself by looking for updated object timestamps in your folder or setting up S3 event notifications.